# Simple HTML/Javascript page created by Python shows as blank

Tags: javascript, python, html, leaflet, folium

I was just following this [tutorial](https://folium.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) about Folium - a Python library that makes web maps. The tutorial states that a web map can be created with only these three lines of Python code:

```
import folium
map_osm = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
map_osm.create_map(path='osm.html')
```

[This](http://bl.ocks.org/wrobstory/5545719) is how the osm.html should look like according to the tutorial.

However, the osm.html file is showing up as just a blank webpage on my browsers.

Here is the source code of my osm.html file if that helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
   <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0/develop/dist/leaflet.awesome-markers.css">
   <script src="//rawgithub.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0/develop/dist/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/MarkerCluster.css">
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//birdage.github.io/Leaflet.awesome-markers/dist/leaflet.awesome.rotate.css">






   <style>

      html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #map {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        left:0;
      }

   </style>
</head>

<body>

   <div class="folium-map" id="folium_62f4bc18e7a1444b908b0413335a38b1" style="width: 960px; height: 500px"></div>

   <script>



      var base_tile = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          maxZoom: 18,
          minZoom: 1,
          attribution: 'Map data (c) <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      });

      var baseLayer = {
        "Base Layer": base_tile
      };

      /*
      addition of the wms layers
      */



      /*
      addition of the tile layers
      */


      /*
      list of layers to be added
      */
      var layer_list = {

      };

      /*
      Bounding box.
      */
      var southWest = L.latLng(-90, -180),
          northEast = L.latLng(90, 180),
          bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

      /*
      Creates the map and adds the selected layers
      */
      var map = L.map('folium_62f4bc18e7a1444b908b0413335a38b1', {
                                       center:[20, 40],
                                       zoom: 10,
                                       maxBounds: bounds,
                                       layers: [base_tile]
                                     });

      L.control.layers(baseLayer, layer_list).addTo(map);

      //cluster group
      var clusteredmarkers = L.markerClusterGroup();
      //section for adding clustered markers

      //add the clustered markers to the group anyway
      map.addLayer(clusteredmarkers);













   </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I just tried running your code, and it worked perfectly — at least using Safari 8.0.7.

Comment: @aaplmath I am using Firefox and Chrome. Did you try the HTML code I posted or did you create your own HTML by running the Python code?

Comment: I tried the HTML you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HTML you posted, all of the `<link>` and `<script>` tags use [protocol relative URLs](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

> If the browser is viewing that current page in through HTTPS, then it’ll request that asset with the HTTPS protocol, otherwise it’ll typically request it with HTTP.
>
> Of course, if you’re viewing the file locally, it’ll try to request the file with the `file://` protocol.

I think you viewed the file locally, so the browser tried to find the non-existent script/CSS files on your computer. Simply adding `http:` before all the links would work.

Answer (score 2):

The html files created by folium are designed to be viewed through the http protocol. As user880772 answered, they won't work if you open the file directly in your browser (`file://` method) unless you manually change all the relative urls into urls prepended with `http://`.

To proceed by viewing the file through http (without having to edit the html): in a terminal, in the directory containing the html file, run:

```
# Python 2.x
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

or

```
# Python 3.x
python -m http.server
```

Then visit `http://localhost:8000/` in your browser and navigate to the html file created by folium.

See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally for more information.